# Is there a way to make a setUp and tearDown methods on tape?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, tap, node.js-tape

I am using [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) for testing in JavaScript, but in some cases I want to set some configuration variables that are available in all the tests within a file. Something like the setUp and tearDown methods available in PhpUnit. Those methods will be executed before and after every test in the file, respectively.

e.g:

```
test("setUp", function(t){
    var person = {name: 'Jose', programmer: true};
});

test("Name isn't undefined", function(){
    t.notEqual(person.name, undefined);
});

test("Is a programmer", function(t){
    t.ok(person.programmer);
});

test("tearDown", function(){
    //Do something else
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little too late for the reply but yes there is.
By [substack](https://gist.github.com/substack/9561717) himself.

Basically you just write it simply as another test spec but with `setup` and `teardown`.

```
test('setup', function(t){
t.end();
});
test('teardown', function(t){
t.end();
});
```